# how to show scroll indicators on table view

Tags: android, scroll, titanium, scrollbar, tableview

Is there any way to indicate to the user that a table is scrollable on Android. I see in the API there is a 'showVerticalScrollInidicator' boolean property which can be set for iOS but not Android. Any way around this?

Comment: Use `GridView` or `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

Insted of table, the preferable way is to use ListView in Android. It offers much better memory management and easy to use API through adapters. About the scroll being visible, ListView comes with `android:fadeScrollbars="false"`

If you insist upon using TableView in Android, the way to do it is putting your TableView in a ScrollView and using `android:fadeScrollbars="false"` in that

Hope that helps